# How to retrieve table datas using SHOW TABLES

Tags: mysql

I have 5 tables in my database :

> Torneio1,Torneio2,Torneio3,Torneio4,Toneio5.

They all have the same structure.

```
id_position INT (primary key).
id_school int
name varchar
points int
```

I want to get all the tables that have at least one record where `id_school = 3`.

I've tried with

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'Torneio%' where id_school =3
```

But I get a syntax error.

Comment: If you get an Error you have to insert it in your question...

Comment: This reeks of terrible schema design. You should never have to do something like this in a relational database

Comment: Phil , this is only a database to learn some query commands, but you are right. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what output you want, but if it is to determine which of the tables contain rows with that particular value you could use this ugly union solution:

```
select 'Torneio1' as tbl from Torneio1 where id_school = 3
union all
select 'Torneio2' as tbl from Torneio2 where id_school = 3
union all
select 'Torneio3' as tbl from Torneio3 where id_school = 3
union all
select 'Torneio4' as tbl from Torneio4 where id_school = 3
union all
select 'Torneio5' as tbl from Torneio5 where id_school = 3
```

This would print the names of the matching tables.